# What do you call this implicit loop syntax in PHP?

Tags: php

Scratching my head looking at this render function:

```
public function render($layout, $echo=false)
    {   
        if ($this->_escape)
        {   
            foreach ($this as $n => &$v)
            {   
                if (0) {
                } elseif (is_array($v) or is_object($v)) {
                    $this->htmlspecialchars_recursive($v);
                } elseif (is_scalar($v)) {$v=htmlspecialchars($v,ENT_QUOTES,null,false);}
            }   
        }   

        if ($echo) { $this->insert($layout); return true;
        } else { ob_start(); $this->insert($layout); return ob_get_clean(); }
    }
```

I understand that the ampersand means that we're modifying the contents of the collection (associative array in this case?) that we're iterating over, but what's up with this `if (0)` business?

There's some sort of implicit iteration stuff going on here, what's this called in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "this refactor is incomplete".

It appears that there was originally 3 if cases used, and the first one became no longer valid. Instead of just removing it, the author changed it to `if(0)`, which will always evaluate to false.

The correct way would be to modify it to this

```
if (is_array($v) or is_object($v)) {
    $this->htmlspecialchars_recursive($v);
}
elseif (is_scalar($v)) { 
    $v=htmlspecialchars($v,ENT_QUOTES,null,false);
}
```

The ampersand in the `foreach` is the reference symbol. `$this` is an object, and `$n` will be the property names and `$v` will be the property value. Without the `&` you get a copy of the property value. With the `&` you get a reference to the property, ie: you are changing the actual property value.

Comment: Miller-Time > linter for this dev ;-)

Comment: rofl now that I look at it I can't believe I didn't see it XD